# Is there some way in which we can view the usage statistics of existing QuickSight reports and dashboards?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

Context: As a new intern at a firm, one of my responsibilities is to maintain a clean and ordered QuickSight Analysis and Datasets list.

There are a lot of existing analysis reports and dashboards on the firm's Amazon QuickSight account, dating back to several years. There is a concern of deleting the old reports/supporting datasets which take up a lot of SPICE storage because of the thought that *someone* is using/accessing it. Is there a way one can see the stats of each report - how many people accessed it, how many times it was used over the last month etc., which could help one decide the analysis reports/datasets that can be deleted. Please help.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to get usage information but you could remove access to analysis and dashboards that you think people are no longe using and verify that no one complains :)

Comment: Too many reports or dashboards to try this but I can try. Thanks! :)

Comment: There is a newer post by AWS answering this question more directly: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/run-usage-analytics-on-amazon-quicksight-using-aws-cloudtrail/

Answer (score 1):

This AWS blog post -- [Using administrative dashboards for a centralized view of Amazon QuickSight objects](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/using-administrative-dashboards-for-a-centralized-view-of-amazon-quicksight-objects/) -- discussed how BI administrators can use the QuickSight dashboard, Lambda functions, and other AWS services to create a centralized view of groups, users, and objects access permission information and abnormal access auditing.
It is mainly security focused, but you can get the idea, how to find the relevant information about access to QuickSight objects in the AWS CloudTrail events.